# Azure databricks. java error by reading data from sql database

Tags: azure, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, databricks, indexoutofboundsexception

I have several notebooks where I make a connection to a sql server and retrieve data by a query. However, now I have a notebook where I need to get data from the same server, but another database.

The code:

```
sql_fcd = "(SELECT column_a, columns_b FROM myTable) a"

df_fcd = spark.read.jdbc(url = jdbcMetadataParams["url"], table = "FCD.snelheidStatistiekenSegment", properties = jdbcMetadataParams["properties"])
```

This results in the error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 65535, Size: 0
```

Off course I checked the parameters used in the spark.read.jdbc command. Url for sql-server/database and username and password are OK.

When I change the tablename in the query to a table that does not exist, I get an error that the tabel does not exist (as expected). So connection properties are OK. I also tried another tabel that is present on the database, but that gives the same error.

What can cause this error? Is there something that needs to be configured at the database-level?

Full error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2272842214196692> in <module>
     18 # put data in dataframes
     19 #df_basis = spark.sql(sql_basis)
---> 20 df_koppeltabel = spark.read.jdbc(url = jdbcMetadataParams["url"], table = sqlKoppeltabel, properties = jdbcMetadataParams["properties"])

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in jdbc(self, url, table, column, lowerBound, upperBound, numPartitions, predicates, properties)
    632             jpredicates = utils.toJArray(gateway, gateway.jvm.java.lang.String, predicates)
    633             return self._df(self._jreader.jdbc(url, table, jpredicates, jprop))
--> 634         return self._df(self._jreader.jdbc(url, table, jprop))
    635 
    636 

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    125     def deco(*a, **kw):
    126         try:
--> 127             return f(*a, **kw)
    128         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    129             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o777.jdbc.
: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 65535, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.StreamColumns.processDataClassification(StreamColumns.java:303)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.StreamColumns.setFromTDS(StreamColumns.java:228)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$1CursorInitializer.onColMetaData(SQLServerResultSet.java:282)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:109)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.<init>(SQLServerResultSet.java:391)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1642)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:600)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:522)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7225)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3053)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:247)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:222)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:444)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:376)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:402)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: please post the full stacktrace

Comment: Done (I hope this is what you mean with Stack Trace :) )

Comment: from stacktrace I would say that this is a bug in the MS SQL JDBC driver. The version of the driver included depends on the databricks runtime version. You can find it in the databricks runtime release notes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/releases

Comment: BTW, we encouter the same problem with datafactory for some tables. Micrisift is contacted about this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the problem. On the sql tabels that caused this error, sensitivity calssifications were added. This causes problems for Databricks and Datafactory. Removing these classifications solved the problem